# How to post checked values of radiolist to database?

Tags: php, yii2, radio-button, radio-group, active-form

I am trying to create a Quiz app, with many MCQ questions that are stored in Database. I successfully get questions and options from Db and display it.

However, when I try to post the checked values to Db it doesn't work.

I am using `ActiveForm` and `RadioList` inside of it.

All data is taken from Db using for loop.

Also, I need to pass the `question_id` when posting the checked value.

I have Tables:

Questions - questions table.

Answers - table where I want to write the checked values.

Options - Table from where I get the options(a,b,c) for the questions.

Answers Controller:

```
public function actionSave()
    {
        $model = new Answers;
        $request = \Yii::$app->getRequest();
        if ($request->isPost && $model->load($request->post())) {
            \Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
            return ['success' => $model->save()];
        }
        return $this->renderAjax('index', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }

    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Answers;
        $this->save($model);
    }


    protected function save($model)
    {
        if (isset($_POST['Answers'])) {
            $model->attributes = $_POST['Answers'];
            if ($model->save()) {
                $this->redirect(array('index'));
            }
        }
        $this->render('_form', compact('model'));
    }
```

Here is the view:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
<?php for ($i=0; $i<count($questions); $i++): ?>    
    <div>
        <?= Html::encode("{$questions[$i]->title}") ?>
    </div>

    <?php $options = Options::find()->where(['question_id'=>$questions[$i]->id])->orderBy('id ASC')->all();
        $options = ArrayHelper::map($options,'id', 'title');?>

        <label class="container" >
            <?= $form->field($model, 'option_id')->radioList($options, ['name'=>'Questions['.$questions[$i]->id.']', 'separator' => '<br>' ])->label(false) ?>        
        </label>

<?php endfor; ?>

<?= Html::submitButton('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

I expect that when user answers all questions and press the "Save" button, it will save the checked value and `question_id` to the table in Db. However, now it do nothing, and do not show any errors.

I am working on this first time, so please can you help me to understand how to do it?

Answer (score -1):

We are lacking the code of the model, as it is right now you could do:

1. Dump the post inside the action with `var_dump($request->post());die();`
2. Check if the values are on the post.
3. Check if the field name are in the rules of the class.
4. Check if the name of the field in the post is right.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't add the model code because it is almost empty (only the rules). Is there something else I need to write?